# edgebundle doesn't render plot when in loop in markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, data-visualization, igraph

I'm trying to create an automated report where I create a series of chord graphs using edgebundleR.

I have a function that does a bunch of stuff and has more or less this form:

```
plot_chords <- function(x,t,pos) {
  ...
  stuff I do with the data
  ...
  g <- graph.adjacency(mydata, mode="upper", weighted=TRUE, diag=FALSE)
  return(edgebundle(g))
}
```

This function works properly if I don't use it inside a loop. It doesn't if it is in a loop like this:

````
```{r echo = FALSE,message=FALSE, warning = FALSE,results = "asis"}
for (c in unique(df$Group)) {

  cat("\n\n## ",c," - Negative Correlations (min r=",t_neg," - only significative)\n\n")
  plot_chords(subset(df, Group == c),0.5,0)

}
```
````

I found that in general, this doesn't work inside loops unless I use print:

```
for (c in unique(df$Group)) {
  temp=df[df$Group == c,]
  print(plot_chords(temp,0.5,0))
}
```

But print doesn't work in markdown.

How can I render the plot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `edgebundle` call returns an `htmlwidget` and works, as you noted, well when not in a loop.  A solution to your situation would be use the `for` loop to generate several specific R code chunks in a temporary file and then evaluate that that temporary file as a child file in your primary .Rmd file.

For example, in a .Rmd file these two chunks will load the needed packages and define a function `foo` which creates and shows a random edgebundle.

````
```{r}
set.seed(42)
library(edgebundleR)
library(igraph)
```

## test the function

```{r}
foo <- function() {
  adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.4)), nc = 10)
  g <- graph.adjacency(adjm)
  edgebundle(g)
}
```
````

Calling `foo` twice in a chunk will work as expected in the output `.html` document.

````
```{r}
foo()
foo()
```
````

To generate several edgebudles in a `for` loop try this.  Write a `for` loop to populate a `temp.Rmd` file with the needed R chunks.  You will need to modify this as needed for your application.

````
## test the function in a for loop

```{r}
tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
for(i in 1:3) {
  cat("### This is edgebundle", i, "of 3.\n```{r}\nfoo()\n```\n",
      file = tmpfile, append = TRUE) 
}
```
````

The contents of `tmpfile` look like this:

````
### This is edgebundle 1 of 3.
```{r}
foo()
```
### This is edgebundle 2 of 3.
```{r}
foo()
```
### This is edgebundle 3 of 3.
```{r}
foo()
```
````

To display the widgets in your primary output file use a chunk like this:

````
```{r child = tmpfile}
```
````

---

The full `.Rmd` file and result:

**example.Rmd:**

````
# edgebundleR and knitr
Answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926520/edgebundle-doesnt-render-plot-when-in-loop-in-markdown

```{r}
set.seed(42)
library(edgebundleR)
library(igraph)
```

## test the function

```{r}
foo <- function() {
  adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.4)), nc = 10)
  g <- graph.adjacency(adjm)
  edgebundle(g)
}
foo()
foo()
```

## test the function in a for loop

```{r}
tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
for(i in 1:3) {
  cat("### This is edgebundle", i, "of 3.\n```{r}\nfoo()\n```\n",
      file = tmpfile, append = TRUE) 
}
```

```{r child = tmpfile}
```

```{r}
print(sessionInfo(), local = FALSE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an easier (and more elegant) solution, but this one does the job.